# Taking advantage of Sage and IPython notebook in the same page? Or, rather combining them?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sage

I'm new to both Sage and Python. For writing sage program, I went to sagemath cloud, and when I tried to create a new file, I had, among others, two options: sage worksheet and IPython notebook. I noticed both does coloring and indentation. But I was wondering: is there any way to take advantage of both of them together? How can I combine both of them together? For example, in IPython notebook, how can I make it understand the sage commands?

To give an explicit and concrete example of the above, in Sage tutorials, there's factor(-2007). If you run it on sage worksheet, it gives (as you expect), -1*3^2*223, but in IPython notebook, it shows 'factor' is not defined. How can I write factor(-2007) in IPynb, run it, and get -1*3^2*223?

I'm working in a windows 8, 64 bit environment, just if it is relevant.

Comment: The following question may help you, though I think some of it may be outdated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412386/ipython-sage-dependencies-anaconda-and-package-integration

Answer (score 10):

On a machine with everything properly configured, e.g., https://cloud.sagemath.com, you can just type

```
%load_ext sage
```

into an IPython notebook cell, and then you can use Sage (except plotting graphics might not work *yet*).  I've attached a screenshot showing this.  (NOTE: I've edited this answer, but not the screenshot -- the extension used to be more complicated.)

[image]

Comment: I'm a sagemath.com newb but it appears to me that this should now be:

%load_ext sage

which is what's suggested under the 'i' icon in the iPyNB page.

Comment: Hi -- when I wrote that answer it was write.  However, it has since *changed* to `%load_ext sage`, which is now the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the IPython notebook is now the **Jupyter notebook**.

To use Sage in a Jupyter notebook worksheet, you can either

- use the Python2 kernel, and start with `%load_ext sage`, or
- use the SageMath kernel, and then you don't need `%load_ext sage`.

To change kernel, use the `Kernel > Change Kernel` menu item, from
the menu bar that has `File`, `Edit`, `View`, `Insert`, `Kernel`, `Help`.

Also, there is now a **native SageMath installer for Windows**,
which you can get from

- https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/releases

and which works with any 64-bit Windows.

This will let you use SageMath using the Sage REPL
(or command-line  interface), or the Jupyter notebook,
or the legacy SageNB notebook.

You should also be able to install JupyterLab by opening a
Sage shell and running `sage --pip install jupyterlab`, and
then you can launch JupyterLab by running `sage -n jupyterlab`.

Similarly, `sage -n jupyter` gives you the Jupyter notebook,
and `sage -n sagenb`gives you the legacy SageNB notebook.

All this also works on [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com), the new name
of SageMathCloud.